# Content editor not loading external javascript file

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm using a content link for my content editor. In this js file I'm tyring to load external javascript file but somehow it is not loading. Here is my code.

$(document).ready(function() {

 Test();  

});

The method Test which is in testscript.js file never gets called.

I tried all combinations of relative paths. I also tried full URL but none of them worked.

Can someone help me in this regrads?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a script editor webpart instead.
But if you're going with CEWP, then upload a text file with all the references of the js files (including jquery).

1.Write this in your text file:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="(relative path)/testscript.js">
</script>
```

2. Upload this text file on in a SP Library on your site.
3. In the CEWP properties, give the link of this text file.

Answer (score 0):

FYI add js reference.

```
script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
(your code)
/script>
```

Comment: Reference is alredy added in the above code which I posted but it is not showing up here. It is like <script type="text/javascript" src="/AdminDocs/testscript.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

If your farm is hosted on secure connection like "https://odmain.com", or if it is SharePoint online, You need to  refer script from secure site. For more information,check the console in developer tools in the Browser.